Why is my Reference Model not refreshing?
I want to programmatically refresh the Reference Model in Tekla Structures. This is what my program looks like:
public static readonly Model model = new Model();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (model.GetConnectionStatus())
    {
        ReferenceModel referenceModel = model.GetModelObjectSelector()
            .GetAllObjectsWithType(new[] { typeof(ReferenceModel) })
            .ToAList<ReferenceModel>().Where(part => part.Filename == @"path")
            .FirstOrDefault();

        bool refreshed = referenceModel.RefreshFile();
    }
} 

referenceModel has been found. But refreshed always returns false. The path contains the exact file of the new version. Because when I press the button in Tekla, the Reference Model actually updates.
I tried to update all existing Reference Models to check if the Refresh method works at all. And I didn’t get exactly what I expected. Here is my code:
foreach (ReferenceModel referenceModel in referenceModels)
{
    if (referenceModel.RefreshFile())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{referenceModel.Filename} updated");
    }
    referenceModel.Modify();
}

I got some links here. But nothing has been updated in Tekla Structures.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

I found the solution of this problem. You have to save model to see the changes. You can do it manually, and you can do it programmatically. Like this:
ModelHandler modelHandler = new ModelHandler();
modelHandler.Save(null, null);

Hope this will be useful to someone.
